# Why isn't ServiceStack adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the GET request?

Tags: servicestack, cors

I configured ServiceStack to enable CORS:

```
Plugins.Add( new CorsFeature(
    allowOriginWhitelist: new List<string>() { "http://localhost", "http://localhost:8080" },
    allowCredentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Allow, Authorization"
) );

PreRequestFilters.Add( ( request, response ) =>
{
    if( request.Verb == "OPTIONS" )
    {
        response.EndRequest();
    }
} );
```

The OPTIONS request and response look great and succeed with the `http://localhost:8080` as the origin. However, the subsequent GET fails because, according to Chrome, it's missing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Here's the error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `http://localhost:8080` is therefore not allowed access.

Here's the request:

```
GET /app/api/operations/metadata HTTP/1.1
Host: dummy.domain.net
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Referer: http://localhost:8080/dev.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

And here's the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.034 Win32NT/.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Allow, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 20 Dec 2014 17:22:38 GMT
Content-Length: 38203
```

Note the missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceStack's CorsFeature [already handles OPTIONS requests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/CorsFeature.cs#L94) so you need to **remove** this so it doesn't short-circuit the request.

```
//Should be removed
PreRequestFilters.Add((request,response) => {
    if (request.Verb == "OPTIONS" )
    {
        response.EndRequest();
    }
});
```

### WhiteList added to Custom Http Handlers

I've added support for Origin White lists in Custom Http Handlers like `/operations/metadata` [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/709fb73c1450f13ba6449eed9101e588775c3d9d). This now works as expected as seen in in http://test.servicestack.net ([source code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Test/blob/1e6c79b5146fe35761cdd830f69f2c530070d658/src/Test/Test/AppHost.cs#L65-L68)):

HTTP Request

```
GET http://test.servicestack.net/operations/metadata HTTP/1.1
Host: test.servicestack.net
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Origin: http://localhost:8080
```

HTTP Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.00 Win32NT/.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Allow, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 21 Dec 2014 00:30:39 GMT
Content-Length: 17027
```

This change is available from **v4.0.35+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: That didn't fix the problem. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that short pre-filter just skips the full set of ServiceStack processing knowing that all we want are the headers, which get added here anyway. My problem is with the GET request; the OPTIONS request is working great. Thanks!

Comment: @Seth Right it stops all further processing so can interfere with existing functionality. I've updated answer to show a fix for this was added in v4.0.35+.

Comment: thank you for this fix, but it's still not quite working. The response to the GET method needs to have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with the request's Origin header as its value.

Comment: It looks like your fix for duplicate headers in 4.0.36 (maybe) might have yanked the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header out of the response you show above? I'm no longer receiving it. Run an OPTIONS and a GET request against http://test.servicestack.net to see it.

Comment: The Test Service specifies an [Origin Whitelist](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Test/blob/master/src/Test/Test/AppHost.cs#L67) so it needs to be supplied a matching `Origin` HTTP Header.

Comment: Thank you @mythz this is working great as of 4.0.38 - just like you said it would be :)